# How do I initialize boost::any with a reference to an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-any

I want to store a reference to an object in a `boost::any` object. How do I initialize the boost::any object? I tried `std::ref()`, but `boost::any` gets initialized with `std::reference_wrapper<>`. For example, the following

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  int s;
  int i = 0;
  boost::any x(std::ref(i));
  std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(x.type().name(), 0, 0, &s) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
std::reference_wrapper<int>
```

I want the `boost::any` to contain `int&` instead.

Comment: As an aside, there is no type_info for reference types, instead the type_info for the type being referenced is taken `cout << typeid(int).name() << "\t" << typeid(int&).name() << "\t" << typeid(int) == typeid(int&)` produces `i     i     1`, so even if the any did store a reference, its type would still be `typeid(int)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `boost::any` class doesn't have an interface allowing something like this: you would need to specify the type of the reference with the constructor. I don't think that you can explicitly specify the type of templated constructor because I don't see any place you could stick it. Even if you can explicitly specify the template parameter, it wouldn't work in C++2003 bcause there is no reference collapsing available and the parameter is declared as taking a `T const&`: you'd be trying to create a `T& const&` which won't fly.
I think your best option is to either use `std::reference_wrapper<T>` if you insist on something looking remotely reference like or just to use `T*`.

That said, it would be generally possible to have a templatized static factor method of a type similar to `boost::any` which would be used to explicitly specify the template argument. However, since `boost::any` is deliberately designed to deal with *value types* this isn't done. I'm a bit dubious whether it should be done as well: using a pointer is perfectly good alternative. If you really need a reference type you'll probably have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour is correct, expected and appropriate. `std::ref` is a helper function that creates an object of type `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, and the reference wrapper is a class with value semantics that holds a reference -- that's exactly the sort of thing you want to put into a container if you want the container to track outside references.

So just go with the solution you have.

If you will, you cannot have a container of direct, naked references, much like you cannot have an array of references. The wrapper is designed precisely to accommodate such needs.